# Dynamic imports in monaco-editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

How can I dynamically call `addExtraLibs` in monaco-editor with content from custom source?

So when user typed `import {} from "somelib"` I got some event or hook where I could call `axios.get("/libs", {params: "somelib"})` from where I got somelib source code and add it to editor.

What other way additional to monaco-editor could help me to implement this?